# Song from dance video on Tudou

Tags: identify-this-song

Here is the video link: http://www.tudou.com/programs/view/ellbyoTQbHw

In this dance video, from 02:55 to 03:10, the most drastic part.

I can recognize other parts of this dance, but here the speed is too rapid for me to hear the lyrics clear.

If you don't know the background music from 02:55 to 03:10, could you please write down the lyrics you heard in this 15 seconds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the song, but I'm unable to find the specific recording featured in that video. The song is "First Transformation" from [*Jekyll & Hyde*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jekyll_%26_Hyde_(musical)), the musical. The snippet in the video you linked is from the end of song when (you guessed it) Dr. Jekyll undergoes his first transformation into Mr. Hyde. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tLgUwRw9RhQ&t=188) is the original broadway recording of the song; you should be able to recognize it, but the singer is a bit more—menacing.

The lyrics at the end (full lyrics can be found [here](http://www.metrolyrics.com/first-transformation-jekyll-hyde-lyrics-david-hasselhoff.html)) are:

> Suddenly
>
> Out of breath!
>
> What is this?
>
> Is this death?
>
> ---
>
> Suddenly!
>
> Look at me!
>
> Can it be?
>
> Who is this creature that I see!?